# Which HTTP code should be used when redirecting the user to a new URL based on cookies they have set?

Tags: php, http, redirect, http-response-codes

I have a few "filter" forms on my site, to let people filter the content they're seeing.  I set a cookie when they select these items, so that their preferences are saved.

When they click on the filters they end up with a URL like

```
www.example.com/filters/news,sport/
```

I then use the cookies so that if they navigate to

```
www.example.com/
```

afterwards, they get automatically redirected via PHP's `Header` function to

```
www.example.com/filters/news,sport/
```

I do this (changing the URL as well as just changing the content) so that if they want to share a URL with another person, they see the same content.

My question is what should the HTTP code on that redirect be?  I think 307 (Temporary Redirect), but I'm far from sure.

Comment: Either 302 or 307 should work. It's a temporary redirect because it will be different if the cookie changes.

Comment: I believe `302` is the default code used when you send `header("Location: ...")`